# bakomatex installation problem

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

**The Problem**
Installed deb package for bakomatex and have been getting errors with dpkg ever since.

```
debanjan@tanrake:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for debanjan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up bakoma-tex:i386 (10.1.0-130131) ...
/opt/bakoma/bin/linux/setupcon: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing bakoma-tex:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bakoma-tex:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Steps taken to rectify the problem**

```
debanjan@tanrake:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up bakoma-tex:i386 (10.1.0-130131) ...
/opt/bakoma/bin/linux/setupcon: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing bakoma-tex:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bakoma-tex:i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install **libgtk2.0-0** for **i386**, type the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Actually `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` belongs to libgtk2.0-0:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libgtk2.0-0/filelist

Comment: worked like a charm! could you please explain the reasoning behind this? or link to a similar explanation?

Comment: Well you were building for i386 and a quick package search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ gave me the right package, just use "Search the contents of packages" to get this [result page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=i386)